# Setting the text in a textbox to last months date

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am wanting a textbox to load the date but one month back. So if it 7.14.17 it will be 6.14.17 on page load. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please enter some of your code so we can see what you are trying to do, and see what you have already attempted. Please read [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to properly ask questions that have a better change of receiving a positive and helpful answer. Without any detailed information about your issue, no one here can truly assist you

Comment: DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1)

Comment: Don't forget to decide what you want to do if today's date did not exist in the previous month (e.g there is a 31st of May but no 31st of April).

Comment: @Blackwood I did not think of that.. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
YouTextBox.Text = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("d")
```

to put the date in the textbox. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for other date format strings if needed.

Comment: .AddMonths not .AddMonth :)

Answer (score 0):

So after I posted I tinkered a bit and got this to work.

```
startDate.Text = DateAdd("m", -1, Date.Today)
```

startDate is the id of my textbox I want to populate the date into. Works well. Open to suggests if anybody has a better way.

Comment: Just FYI, `DateAdd()` is a legacy function for backwards compatibility with older VB6/VBA code.  You should use the newer, native, .Net methods as they are generally easier to read and understand.  Additionally, the code will then port over to C# if that ever becomes a necessity.